# How to Write-Verbose from Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

In powershell

`Write-Verbose` and the `-Verbose` flag are used to provide verbose information when commands are run in verbose mode. I am running some scripts remotely and would like to capture the verbose output output. However, `Invoke-Command` seems to not capture the verbose channel.

```
PS:> Invoke-Command -ComputerName MY-COMPUTERNAME -Verbose { Write-Verbose "blah" }
PS:>
```

How do I capture verbose output when running remote scripts?

Comment: Looks like this is a bug with PowerShell. I've created a bug request that you can go up-vote at https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/806241/invoke-command-does-not-pass-the-verbose-parameter-to-remote-session

Comment: This will copy the current preference from the current cmdlet to the remote cmdlet: 
Invoke-Command $session { $VerbosePreference = $Using:VerbosePreference; }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MY-COMPUTERNAME  {$VerbosePreference='Continue'; Write-Verbose "blah" }
```

Comment: I see, so it's not that the verbose channel doesn't get captured so much as the `-Verbose` flag does not pass the VerbosePreference into the remote context (what the heck does it even do then?). Any idea how to set the remote VerbosePreference without modifying the script itself?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that just within invoke-command.  You could create a custom session that has that preference as it's default, and then target your invoke-commnad to that session. but the default for that prefernce variable is 'SilentlyContinue', and the only option you have with invoke-command is to reset it in the script block.

Comment: What the -Verbose switch is doing in your example is enabline Verbose output of the invoke-command cmdlet if your local $VerbosePreference is set to disply it.  Unfortunately it doesn't appear to generate any verbose output, so basically it doesn't do anything.....

Answer (score 21):

Best thing I think you could do is create a function that has [CmdletBinding()] so it supports the -verbose switch.  Then you would be able to capture the verbose state of the local function using the local $VerbosePreference and pass it along in the invoke command.  This will only work in Powershell 3.0 and higher, since you will need to use the $Using scope modifier.

```
Function write-blah{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MY-COMPUTERNAME  {$VerbosePreference=$Using:VerbosePreference; Write-Verbose "blah" }
}
```

Then you would call your function like this.

```
Write-Blah -verbose
```

In testing this has worked for me.  I believe your function must support parameters, hence the empty Param() block.

Comment: Preferable answer, since it is more generic.

Comment: Nice, though in my case it made the output too verbose, as I got hundreds of import/export messages from some cmdlets which loaded modules into the remote context. As workaround I'm using [parameter default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.1) to pass `-Verbose` only to `Write-Verbose` calls instead of all cmdlets: `$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ "Write-Verbose:Verbose" = $using:VerbosePreference }`

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MY-COMPUTERNAME { Write-Verbose "blah" -Verbose }
```