# How to pass -Verbose parameter to a function called inside Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I have the following function that I am trying to invoke remotely with verbose output, but I don't know how to pass the VerbosePreference correctly?

```
function TestVerbose()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Write-Output "output test"
    Write-Verbose "verbose test"
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName computerB -ScriptBlock ${function:TestVerbose}
```

The question [How to Write-Verbose from Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197021/how-to-write-verbose-from-invoke-command) nicely describes how to write something verbose if I have a non-function scriptblock:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computerB {$VerbosePreference='Continue'; Write-Verbose "verbose test"}
```

However, I would like to pass a function and also indicate verbose preference. How to do that?

I have tried combining the function with some inline scriptblock, but it makes the function not run at all:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName computerB -ScriptBlock {$VerbosePreference='Continue'; ${function:TestVerbose}}
```

Answer (score 1):

kind of a workaround. store the current value of verbosepreference , change it in your function and then reset to original value.

```
function TestVerbose()
{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
begin
{
    $VerbosePreference_original = $VerbosePreference
    $VerbosePreference = 'continue'
    Write-Verbose ('Begin:Original value of VerbosePreference : {0}' -f $VerbosePreference_original)
    Write-Verbose ('Begin:New value of VerbosePreference : {0}' -f $VerbosePreference)

}

process
{
    Write-Output 'output test'
    Write-Verbose 'output test'
}
end
{

    Write-Verbose ('END:ReSetting value of VerbosePreference to default : {0}' -f $VerbosePreference_original)
    $VerbosePreference = $VerbosePreference_original


}
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however it does not directly allow me to pass a parameter determining whether or not to use verbose. I had already thought of adding a custom VerbosePref parameter that could then be used to set the local VerbosePreference, but this seems like a workaround and not a clean solution:

`function TestVerbose()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param($VerbosePref)
    if ($VerbosePref) { $VerbosePreference = $VerbosePref }
    Write-Output "output test"
    Write-Verbose "verbose test"
}`