# Use Begin, Process, End in Scriptblock

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use the adavanced function features `Begin, Process, End` in a script-block?

For example I've the following script block:

```
$startStopService = {
Param(
    [bool] $startService)    

  if ($startService){
     ...
     Start-Service "My-Service"
  }
  else {
     Stop-Service "My-Service"
  }
}
```

Since I want to be able to control the verbose output of the scriptblock I want to change the block to:

```
$startStopService = {
Param(
    [bool] $startService)    

  Begin {
     $oldPreference = $VerbosePreference 
     $VerbosePreference = $Using:VerbosePreference
  }
  Process {
     if ($startService){
        ...
        Start-Service "My-Service"
     }
     else {
        Stop-Service "My-Service"
     }
  }
  End {
     # Restore the old preference
     $VerbosePreference = $oldPreference 
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use `Begin, Process, End` here, though the scriptblock isn't a cmdlet? I simply want that the `VerbosePreference` gets restored to the old value, regardless an error occurred or not. Of course I could use `try{}finally{}` as an alternative, but I find that `Begin, Process, End` is more intuitive.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, as described in [about_script_blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks):

> Like functions, script blocks can include the DynamicParam, **Begin,
>   Process, and End keywords.** For more information, see about_Functions
>   and about_Functions_Advanced.

---

To test this out, I modified your scriptblock and ran this:

```
$startStopService = {
Param(
    # a bool needs $true or $false passed AFAIK
    # A switch is $true if specified, $false if not included
    [switch] $startService 
 )    

  Begin {
     $oldPreference  = $VerbosePreference 
     Write-Output "Setting VerbosePreference to Continue"

     # $Using:VerbosePreference gave me an error
     $VerbosePreference = "Continue"
  }
  Process {
     if ($startService){
        Write-Verbose "Service was started"
     }
     else {
        Write-Verbose "Service was not started"
     }
  }
  End {
     # Restore the old preference
     Write-Output "Setting VerbosePreference back to $oldPreference"
     $VerbosePreference = $oldPreference 
  }

}

Write-Verbose "This message will not print if VerbosePreference is the default SilentlyContinue"

. $startStopService -startService

Write-Verbose "This message will not print if VerbosePreference is the default SilentlyContinue"
```

---

What functionality are you after? If you would to print verbose messages when running a scriptblock but not change the `$VerbosePreference` in the rest of the script , consider using `[CmdletBinding()]` and the `-Verbose` flag:

```
$startStopService = {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param(
        [switch] $startService
    )

     Write-Verbose "This is a verbose message"

}
Write-Verbose "This message will not print if VerbosePreference is the default SilentlyContinue"

. $startStopService -verbose

Write-Verbose "This message will not print if VerbosePreference is the default SilentlyContinue"
```

---

**Edit - Invoke-Command**

After your comment, I looking into the functionality of `Invoke-Command`. And found a lot of things that don't work.

The short version that I believe is most useful to you: **you can declare `$VerbosePreference = "Continue"` within a scriptblock and this will be limited to the scope of the scriptblock**. No need to change back after.

```
$startStopService = {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Position=0)]
        [switch]$startStopService,

        [parameter(Position=1)]
        [switch]$Verbose
    )

    if($Verbose){
        $VerbosePreference = "Continue"
    }

    Write-Verbose "This is a verbose message"

}

Write-output "VerbosePreference: $VerbosePreference"
Write-Verbose "This message will not print if VerbosePreference is the default SilentlyContinue"

Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $startStopService -ArgumentList ($true,$true)

Write-output "VerbosePreference: $VerbosePreference"
Write-Verbose "This message will not print if VerbosePreference is the default SilentlyContinue"
```

Trying to pass the `-Verbose` switch **CommonParameter** to `Invoke-Command` was a no-go. This uses a standard `Verbose` switch parameter that allows you to pass `$true`/`$false` (or omit) to control the verbose output.

<sub>Related:

[about_Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions)

[about_Functions_Advanced](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced)</sub>

Comment: I was looking for the second option of your answer (`CmdletBinding`). Short question: Will `CmdletBinding` also work at `Invoke-Command` ? Let's say `Invoke-Command -session $remoteSession -scriptblock $startStopService -verbose`.

Comment: @Moerwald The short version is that it _should_, as per `[<CommonParameters>]` [in the documenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command). But it's not working when I try it. Searching, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197021/how-to-write-verbose-from-invoke-command) which you've already read. It mentions this as a bug; not sure if that's the case or there's a mistake in the way we're doing it.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Yes I've read the post. Since it is about 3 years old, I thought there might be a better way around it.

Comment: @Moerwald Agreed. After some research I haven't found much but see edited answer for workaround. Directly passing `-Verbose` as in your comment is not possible AFAIK. `-ArgumentList` can be used but haven't managed to get it to work 100% with named parameters.