# Why isn't Verbose working on Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
try {
    Invoke-Command -Computer $Server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory |
            Where {$_.Name -Match "$DB"} |
            Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Recurse $VerbosePreference='Continue'; -Verbose
    } #-Verbose

    Write-Host "`r`nsuccessfull! " -ForegroundColor yellow -BackgroundColor black
} catch {
    Write-Host "`r`nFAILED!" -ForegroundColor red -BackgroundColor black
    Write-Host "$($error[0])`r`n" -ForegroundColor magenta -BackgroundColor black
}
```

`-Verbose` is not generating any verbose like this:

> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target ...

If I try the following command:

```cs
Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\' |
    Where{$_.Name -Match "text"} |
    Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Recurse -Verbose
```

I actually get back:

> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "E:\text.xml".
>   VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "E:\text.txt".

According to the question [How to Write-Verbose from Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197021/how-to-write-verbose-from-invoke-command) I am supposed to use `$VerbosePreference='Continue';`, but I already tried that as you can see and still I can't get verbose to output anything!

Also, even though no folders get deleted, apparently my `try..catch` STILL outputs that it was successfull. How come?

Comment: i have not tested this ... but i thot that `-Verbose` would send to the _current host_. the current host is running on the remote system in a non-interactive session. i would not expect to see anything from that. ///// again, i have NOT tested the idea - i have only the one system, so i've no way to test it. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i thought that might be it but then look at this, in which the command is verbosing output just fine with remote execution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16197390/8397835

Comment: well, now that i read your code --- it LOOKS like it SHOULD give you a screen full of red error text. [*grin*] this `Remove-Item -confirm:$false -Recurse $VerbosePreference='Continue'; -Verbose` is just flat out WRONG. the verbose pref thing otta be OUTSIDE of the `Remove-Item` call ... likely in front of it. yours is embedded and really, REALLY otta not work at all.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey by in front you mean here: { $VerbosePreference='Continue'; -Verbose Get-ChildItem .... or after everything: ....Remove-Item -confirm:$false -Recurse } $VerbosePreference='Continue'; -Verbose

Comment: i mean the way it is shown in the link you posted. [*grin*] something like `$VerbosePreference='Continue'; Remove-Item -confirm:$false -Recurse -Verbose` ///// plus, you seem to have a stray `}` right after the `-Verbose` in that line of your code.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that bracket is from behind { Get-ChildItem ... so its the end of it

Comment: ha! i missed that ... thanks for the correction! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i found out whats going on. so its actually there is nothing to display if the files dont exist to delete. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/aabedd38-269e-42c0-bc83-e6bd6d6d1f33/why-is-verbose-not-working-with-invokecommand?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: ha! [*grin*] thank you for the why of it ...

Comment: Why is there a ; just before -verbose?

Comment: `$VerbosePreference='Continue'` is a statement of its own (which should be clear from the answers to the question you referenced), it is *not* a valid part of your `Remove-Item` statement.